# Rails app - Referencing images within a stylesheet

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, assets

So I'm working on my new rails app, and within one of my stylesheets I have the pg-parlex class which specifies a background-image link:

```
.bg-parlex {
    padding-top: 0px;
    background-image: url('assets/banner-bg.gif'); /* << THIS URL LINK! */
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Could someone just quickly explain how we link to the assets/images folder an items within...I was sure it was `assets/item1.png` or `assets/item2.png`, but perhaps as the link is inside a stylesheet maybe this is wrong...?

Comment: Are you using scss ?

Comment: Yes, scss. Doesn't give me an error; simply does not load the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
background-image: image-url("rails.png") 
#=> background-image: url(/assets/rails.png)
```

> If you are using [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem:

```
background-image: asset-url("rails.png", image) 
#=> background-image: url(/assets/rails.png)
```

So, your code would be:

```
.bg-parlex {
    ...
    background-image: asset-url("banner-bg.gif", image);
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works, and I've tried this. However. Background-size, repeat and attachment do not work. And the image doesn't scroll with the page.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts, can you try this: `background-image: asset-url("banner-bg.gif", image)` ?

Comment: Still doesn't work as correct as a normal index.html/css setup. I think perhaps I need help on integrating my javascripts into rails